# Probability stick I drop parallel to diagonal of rectangle fits within the rectangle

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-probability

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> A floor is paved with rectangular bricks each $a$ inches long and $b$ inches wide. A stick $c$ inches long is thrown upon the floor so as to fall parallel to a diagonal of the bricks. Show that the chance that it lies entirely on one brick is $(a^2 + b^2 - c^2) \div (a^2 + b^2)$.

Here's what I did. So let's say we have a rectangle of height $a$ and width $b$. Let's say our stick of length $c$ falls parallel to the diagonal going from top left to bottom right. We want to calculate the probability that it lies entirely within this rectangle. Each stick fall is determined by its top left point. If you draw this all out, the part of our $a$ by $b$ rectangle where if the upper left point of our stick is dropped the stick fits entirely in our rectangle, is the upper left part of the rectangle with height $a - {{ac}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}$ and width $b - {{bc}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}$. So the probability we want to calculate is$${{\left(a - {{ac}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)\left(b - {{bc}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)}\over{ab}} = \left(1 - {c\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)^2 = 1 - {{2c}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}} + {{c^2}\over{a^2 + b^2}}.$$However, it's not clear how or if this even equals ${{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}\over{a^2 + b^2}}$. Can anyone help me show that they are equal, or if they aren't, let me know where specifically I went wrong?

**EDIT:** I'm still not convinced by Math Lover's answer. Let's use the diagram he's using. Let's draw rectangle $FCC'F'$, where $F'$ lies on $AC$, $C'$ lies on $CB$, $FF'$ is perpendicular to $DC$, $F'C'$ is perpendicular to $CB$. I claim our desired probability is the area of $FCC'F'$ divided by the area of $ABCD$.

For every stick of length $c$ that falls that's parallel to $AC$, its upper-right endpoint determines it. And only if I select a point in rectangle $FCC'F'$ will its extension by length $c$ in the bottom-left direction parallel to $AC$ lie fully within rectangle $ABCD$.

The length of $FC$ is the length of $DC$ minus the length of $DF$, so following the convention Math Lover uses of the length of $DC$ being $a$ and the length of $DA$ being $b$, the length of $FC$ is $a -{{ac}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}$. Similarly, the length of $CC'$ is $b - {{bc}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}$. Multiplying those two and dividing by $ab$ gets the probability I calculated before the edit, which differs from what Math Lover got.

However, this still differs from the answer we're supposed to find, so can anyone elaborate in further detail Math Lover's initial two sentences in his answer?

> The problem is in how you are calculating the area of the region where the stick should fall. You are multiplying side lengths but the region is not a rectangle.

Comment: I am not sure how you got to your equation. Determine what is the area in which the stick needs to be and than divide by an area of the rectangle.

Comment: @Moti That's literally what I did.

Comment: I do not know how you calculated it, but the ratio of the area is twice the square of the ratio of the diagonals. The diagonals are $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$ and $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}$

Comment: Just a thought, but isn't it better to consider where the center of the stick should fall?

Comment: @Moti The length of the stick is $c$ and this length is measured in the same direction as the diagonal, so why isn't the length of the shorter diagonal $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-c$ ?

Comment: I did delete my answer due to ambiguity and I read through your edit. The point about falling parallel to a diagonal must have been elaborated in the question but my assumption in answering it is that it falls parallel and centered. Otherwise there is really no solution. If the stick is not falling centered, the lines parallel to any diagonal you take is of infinite length. It can fall anywhere on that line and it is parallel to the diagonal. But you want them to fall within a rectangle of finite dimension and the probability of that is practically zero, correct?

Comment: You are right. The small square created is the goal. The edges of the stick need to be in the squares along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The midpoint of the stick should fall inside the red rectangle. If it falls into the blue area, then the stick will touch the borders.

$$a' = c a/(2\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$$
$$b' = c b/(2\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$$

$$
\text{Probability} = \frac{\text{Red area}}{\text{Area of large blue rectangle}} = \frac{(a-2 a')(b-2 b')}{a\, b}
$$

Using the results for $a'$ and $b'$:
$$
\text{Probability} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-c\right)^2}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{2 c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+1
$$

Therefore, I think that the answer reported in the question (namely, $(a^2 + b^2 - c^2) \div (a^2 + b^2)$) is wrong, unless this is some kind of [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). Just to be clear:
$$
\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{ a^2 + b^2} \neq
\frac{\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-c\right)^2}{a^2+b^2}
$$
unless $c=0$ or $c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$: in those extreme cases the probability is 1 and 0, respectively.

**NOTE:** if the stick is thrown **on** the diagonal (and not on a generic line parallel to the diagonal), then using the same argument of the midpoint, it's easy to obtain

$$
\text{Probability} =\frac{\text{diagonal}-(c/2)-(c/2)}{\text{diagonal}}= \frac{ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}-c }{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} 
$$
As @Radost wrote in the comments, it is interesting to note that this probability is exactly the square root of the one we obtained before (it's just an elegant scaling argument: the area of similar rectangles scales with the square of the diagonal).

Comment: Even more direct answer is that red and blue triangles are simply scaled so ratio of their areas is proportional to lengths of respective diagonals squared. Saves computation of a' and b'. Good diagram!

Comment: This is true, you're 100% right! It's nice to observe that the result you obtain when the stick is thrown ON the diagonal is exactly the square root !

Answer (score -1):

Your calculations seem to be correct; you end up with this messy expression:

${{\left(a - {{ac}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)\left(b - {{bc}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)}\over{ab}} = \left(1 - {c\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\right)^2 = 1 - {{2c}\over{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}} + {{c^2}\over{a^2 + b^2}}$

(Sorry I'm not good at mathjax...) Multiply each term so the denominator of all is $a^2+b^2$, and combine terms, getting the numerator:

$(a^2+b^2) - (2c\sqrt{a^2+b^2}) + (c^2)$ ...(1)

Then notice that if you write $x$ for $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, you get

$x^2 - 2cx + c^2$

**Corrected...**

which is obviously $(x - c)^2$, and not $x^2 - c^2$ as the original answer would imply. Thus the original answer is wrong.

Apologies for the wrong answer!

Comment: Thanks @BrianChandler, and welcome to MSE! So I'm able to see that ${{\left(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - c\right)^2}\over{a^2 + b^2}}$ is our desired probability, but I'm not sure how you got that that's equivalent to ${{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}\over{a^2 + b^2}}$. Could you elaborate? Why does $- 2c\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + c^2 = -c^2$?

Comment: I just numbered the 'numerator' expression as (1) - this is what you need to have on the top, and your expression in the comment is different, and not equivalent to the answer.

Comment: The last step in your calculation is literally asserting what I am asking about. I am asking how you are getting that $x^2 - 2cx + c^2$ equals $x^2 - c^2$.

Comment: Oops! You are right of course, and it seems the original answer was wrong.